# Using silverlight plugin for capturing images in asp .net mvc application

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, silverlight, webcam

I am using silverlight plugin for capturing images through webcam and want to save these images in mvc app. so that to use them for retrieving some information.this application is regarding the decoding of barcode image and then making that barcode a unique id so that a particular record from the database will be retrieved accordingly.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: A Silverlight object can be embedded anywhere inside an html mark-up, also you can call web-services or javascript functions. So in theory it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. but can you make it happened without webservices. But thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks i am also using the same concept for the integration but the problem is in saving the images in my application without the use of save dialog box as it is used previously by me.If you can help it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after you've obtained the image from the webcam, the file is stored in a Memory Stream, correct?

Just do a normal HTTP Post to an MVC controller action that includes an HTTPPostedFileBase as one of its parameters:

-- uploading a silverlight memory stream
[Very simple Silverlight File Upload example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622518/very-simple-silverlight-file-upload-example)

-- capturing the file inside MVC
http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx