# Web Client - Asynchronous operations are not allowed in this context

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, webclient, class-library

It is a Class Library and it is getting called form a web page

```
try
  {
    System.Net.WebClient wc = WebAccess.GetWebClient();
    wc.UploadStringCompleted += new System.Net.UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_UploadStringCompleted);
    wc.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("http://" + MobileWLCUrl + urlCreateCacheAPI), GetJSONforGetMenuDetails(Id, MenuIds));                    
  }
catch (Exception ex) { EngineException.HandleException(ex); }

void wc_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, System.Net.UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string result = e.Result;
        EngineException.CreateLog("Cache Created (for Menus: " + MenuIds + ") in API for LocationId: " + LocId);
    }
```

hie guys, m trying to hit this url asynchronously and it is giving me this error, any help will be appriciated.

```
Asynchronous operations are not allowed in this context. 
Page starting an asynchronous operation has to have the Async attribute set to true 
and an asynchronous operation can only be started on a page prior to PreRenderComplete event. 

at System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext.OperationStarted()
at System.Net.WebClient.UploadStringAsync(Uri address, String method, String data, Object userToken)
at System.Net.WebClient.UploadStringAsync(Uri address, String data)
```

Thnx...

Comment: There is no answer for this?? i thought its a common error m facing, really disappointed

Answer (score 10):

Add the `Async="true"` parameter to the @Page directive.

```
<%@ Page Async="true" ... %>
```

Siwani,

You need to apply this change in the page (stored in `"http://" + MobileWLCUrl + urlCreateCacheAPI`) called in following code:

```
wc.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("http://" + MobileWLCUrl + urlCreateCacheAPI), GetJSONforGetMenuDetails(Id, MenuIds));
```

Comment: u mean the page m calling that into?
it is a .cs File
i am calling this class from my page behind Code, I added this but still ho result, it keeps giving me this exception

Comment: Page directives are found on aspx page.

Comment: I added this into page but still no luck

Comment: Sirwani, I think you have modified the page directive on the calling page. Update the directive on the called page in "UploadStringAsync" function.

Comment: Its a class library not an aspx page

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622518/very-simple-silverlight-file-upload-example/1622547#1622547 ,   http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/quickstarts/Accessing_a_REST_Web_Service

Comment: ref didn't helped a bit. Finally there was no result for what i thought was a simple error. Changing the code and going for synchronous option.