# Silverlight convert byte[] to string for Image

Tags: silverlight, azure, encoding, arrays, storage

In my silvelright application, I have an image that is stored in a byte[].  I want to save the image to Azure Blobl Storage using REST services, but it only accepts Strings (UploadStringTaskAsync)

I have tried many ways to convert my byte[] to a valid String but without success :

- Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, data.Length)
- Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, data.Length)
- Even with a custom function (at least that function gives me the right String length)

  var sb = new StringBuilder();
  foreach(byte b in data)
       sb.Append((char)b);

  return sb.ToString();

But the image is always corrupted and/or unreadable on the other side.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: And why not using [UploadDataAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploaddataasync.aspx) ?

Comment: you should ImageConverter

Comment: I cannot use UploadDataAsync, I'm using Silverlight

Comment: What is the ImageConverter your talking about?  How to use it?  Will I really be able to convert from byte[] to String using that method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Convert.FromToBase64String` method on client. Then decode it on server with `Convert.FromBase64String`.

Update:
You can also use `WebClient.OpenWriteAsync` method.

Comment: I cannot control the server since I'm uploading the file to Azure Storage using their REST Api.

Comment: Then you can try `WebClient.OpenWriteAsync`. It works with bytes. The example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622518/very-simple-silverlight-file-upload-example.

Comment: If you need just store the image in BLOB, then you can encode it with `Convert.FromToBase64String` and store string to blob. Later you can take string from blob and decode it with `Convert.FromBase64String`.

Comment: I need it to be stored as a valid file (not Based64String) on the server as it is accessed directly with a url.  The OpenWriteAsync is working now, but I wonder if its possible to upload it as a string...  Thanks